# Replacing text globally with line break in React Native/Javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native, replace, textview, line-breaks

I want to replace an xml tag `<Add` with `\n<Add` so that it open a new line for every `<Add`.

However I tried `.replace(/\<Add/g, '\n')` It shows a blank screen.

I also tried replace it once `.replace('\<Add', '\n')` It works with the first `<Add` replaced by line break. But I need to reaplce all `<Add` with a line break...

Why I can't replace text with "\n" globally? How can I do it in react native?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering:

```
.replace('\<Add', '\n')
```

Works for the first, but not others, do the replacement using the global flag:

```
.replace(/(<Add)/g, '\n$1')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Adds = document.getElementsByTagName('Add')

for (var i=0, max=Adds.length; i < max; i++) {

var br = document.createElement('br');

document.getElementById('container').insertBefore(br, Adds[i])
}
```

Where container is your  direct parent.

See this fiddle for an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/edh4131/bm9avs6u/